# Using pg_search for multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pg-search

Right now I have three models: restaurant, category and item.  All of these table have an attribute for name.  I'd like to set up search on the main page that can access all 3. The search will bring back the restaurant name, category name and / or item name when the search is conducted.

I'm using pg_search in a Rails 4 app.
https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search

So far, I have bundled the gem, set up multi-search and ran the migration.  My models currently look as follows:

MODELS

```
class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :gg, presence: true

  include PgSearch
  multisearchable against: :name

end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :gg, presence: true

  include PgSearch
  multisearchable against: :name

end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :restaurants
  belongs_to :categories

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :gg, presence: true

  include PgSearch
  multisearchable against: :name

end
```

VIEW WITH SEARCHBOX

```
<%= form_tag restaurants_path, method: :get do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query], class: "search-box" %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil, class: "btn btn-search" %>
<% end %>
```

RESTAURANTS CONTROLLER

```
class RestaurantsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @restaurants = PgSearch.multisearch( params[:q] )
  end

end
```

QUESTIONS

- The controller is not getting back the multisearch items properly. How do I write this correctly?
- If I want to implement all three search results on one view, should I set up a new controller or add the categories and items to the restaurants controller as well?
- Please send along any good examples.

Answer (score 3):

When you run the migration, you create a new table called pg_search_documents. That's the table that pg_search will query.

Most likely you have a problem with not having any data in that table. The docs say "If this model already has existing records, you will need to reindex this model to get existing records into the pg_search_documents table. See the rebuild task below."

You want to refer to this section of the documentation: https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search#rebuilding-search-documents-for-a-given-class